# how can we remove that Liferay Logo , Sign In Hyperlinkand Powered BY ?? from the screen

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 and Tomcat for development .
I have developed a Custom Login POrtlet for my Application

Now on entering http://localhost:8086 , my Custom Login Page is displayed .

Please see the screen shot .

[image]

My question is , could anybody tell me how can we remove that Liferay Logo , Sign In Hyperlink ( Extreme right top ) and Powered BY ?? from the screen .

Answer (score 7):

Actually the Logo can be changed without creating a theme. The other items require a cusotm theme however (where you will want to edit the velocity macros). For the logo look under Control Panel > Portal > Portal Settings and then click "Display Settings" on the right side.

Additionally you can also provide a small amount of css to the basic theme as well, but this should be considered a temporary hack at best. Go to Manage > Page Layout > Public Pages and at the bottom you will see a section labled CSS in there you can do:

```
#sign-in { display: none }
.powered-by { display:none }
```

But bear in mind that a user with firebug or similar tools can still expose the old sign-in by changing the CSS in firebug and the Liferay tag line is still in the source so it's only hidden from non-technical folks. A theme is really the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can remove all of those by creating your own Liferay Theme, deploying it, and then setting that Theme as the one to use for your Community.

This [Liferay Wiki Article on creating Theme's](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Themes+v6.0) should get you started, if you have any questions after this then ask away! :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to custom.css file inside _diff folder of your theme add the below code:

```
#sign-in { display: none }
```