# How to remove sign in functionality from Liferay portal

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

How to remove sign in functionality, which will display on right top corner of the Liferay portal guest page?

I tried to delete the #sign-in from custom.css file of classic theme which is the default theme for Liferay, but it did not work.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the link from top right or disable sign in functionality overall..as a user might still access login portlet through the required url '/c/portal/login'

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684117/how-can-we-remove-that-liferay-logo-sign-in-hyperlinkand-powered-by-from-th

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing css in custom.css file of classic theme because it will not load changes of css, provide below css in Control Panel >> Site Pages >>  Look and Feel >> CSS field.

```
#sign-in{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the normal way would be to delete/comment out the velocity script code in theme's portal_normal.vm file.

```
<!--
#if(!$is_signed_in)
<li>
    <a href="$sign_in_url" id="header-sign-in" rel="nofollow">$sign_in_text</a>
</li>
#end
-->
```

Then you can be sure, that there is no login code in your generated jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by you did not worked for me. But I did changes to your code it started working.

the Change I did is as follows:

```
.sign-in{
display:none;
}
```

Instead of '#' I used '.', then its worked for me.

Thank you for the Solution.

Comment: please comment on the original answer rather than giving another answer. This way Pankaj will get a notice and has a chance to correct his answer - and you can accept his answer once it's corrected.